# Reversing characters in each word in a sentence - Stack Implementation

Tags: java, stack, reverse

This code is inside the `main` function:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Type a sentence");
String sentence = input.next();

Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<Character>();
int i = 0;

while (i < sentence.length())
{
    while (sentence.charAt(i) != ' ' && i < sentence.length() - 1)
    {
        stk.push(sentence.charAt(i));
        i++;
    }
    stk.empty();
    i++;
}
```

And this is the `empty()` function:

```
public void empty()
{
    while (this.first != null)
        System.out.print(this.pop());
}
```

It doesn't work properly, as by typing `example sentence` I am getting this output: `lpmaxe`. The first letter is missing and the loop stops instead of counting past the space to the next part of the sentence.

I am trying to achieve this:

`This is a sentence` --->  `sihT si a ecnetnes`

Comment: There is a subtle difference between reversing the words in a sentence and the characters in a sentence. What of both do you want to archieve?

Comment: I want to reverse the characters in each word in the sentence, while keeping the same order of words. And you could say this is homework - I'm just looking online for questions to improve my understanding about the stack & queue.

Comment: Have you tried checking what the value of `sentence` is, and/or what the documentation of [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) says it will do?

Comment: next() only gets one word. Your double loop isn't doing anything after the first round.

Comment: if it's homework, tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per modifications to the original post, where the OP is now indicating that his goal is to reverse the letter order of the words within a sentence, but to leave the words in their initial positions.

The simplest way to do this, I think, is to make use of the String `split` function, iterate through the words, and reverse their orders.

```
String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // splits on the space between words

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String word = words[i];
    System.out.print(reverseWord(word));

    if (i < words.length-1) {
        System.out.print(" "); // space after all words but the last
    }
}
```

Where the method `reverseWord` is defined as:

```
public String reverseWord(String word) {
    for( int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        stk.push(word.charAt(i));
    }
    return stk.empty();
}
```

And where the `empty` method has been changed to:

```
public String empty() {
    String stackWord = "";
    while (this.first != null)
        stackWord += this.pop();
    return stackWord;
}
```

**Original response**

The original question indicated that the OP wanted to completely reverse the sentence.

You've got a double-looping construct where you don't really need it.

Consider this logic:

1. Read each character from the input string and push that character to the stack
2. When the input string is empty, pop each character from the stack and print it to screen.

So:

```
for( int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
    stk.push(sentence.charAt(i));
}
stk.empty();
```

Comment: maybe two loops, one to reverse characters, then one to reverse words. OP wants the sentence with the same word order, each word reversed

Comment: @Jake223 -- the OP changed his post. The original indicated a perfectly reversed sentence. I will edit my response.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you want your code to do is to reverse each word in turn, not the entire string. So, given the input `example sentence` you want it to output `elpmaxe ecnetnes` *not* `ecnetnes elpmaxe`.

The reason that you see `lpmaxe` instead of `elpmaxe` is because your inner `while`-loop doesn't process the last character of the string since you have `i < sentence.length() - 1` instead of `i < sentence.length()`. The reason that you only see a single word is because your `sentence` variable consists only of the first *token* of the input. This is what the method `Scanner.next()` does; it reads the next (by default) space-delimited token.

If you want to input a whole sentence, wrap up `System.in` as follows:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and call `reader.readLine()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already got your input in `sentence` and the Stack object is called `stk`, here's an idea:

```
char[] tokens = sentence.toCharArray();
for (char c : tokens) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        stk.empty();
        System.out.print(c);
    } else  {
        stk.add(c);
    }
}
```

Thus, it will scan through one character at a time. If we hit a space character, we'll assume we've hit the end of a word, spit out that word in reverse, print that space character, then continue. Otherwise, we'll add the character to the stack and continue building the current word. (If you want to also allow punctuation like periods, commas, and the like, change `if (c == ' ') {` to something like `if (c == ' ' || c == '.' || c == ',') {` and so on.)

As for why you're only getting one word, darrenp already pointed it out. (Personally, I'd use a Scanner instead of a BufferedReader unless speed is an issue, but that's just my opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class stringWork {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Hello World";
    s1 = reverseSentence(s1);
    System.out.println(s1);
    s1 = reverseWord(s1);
    System.out.println(s1);
}
private static String reverseSentence(String s1){
    String s2 = "";
    for(int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        s2 += s1.charAt(i);
    }
    return s2;
}
private static String reverseWord(String s1){
    String s2 = "";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        s2 += reverseSentence(st.nextToken());
        s2 += " ";
    }
    return s2;
}
```

}

Comment: consider adding description to your answer

Comment: Don't put only coding, try to say something about your answer or explain it.

Answer (score 0):

public class ReverseofeachWordinaSentance {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "Welcome to the word reversing program";

    for (String str : source.split(" ")) {
        System.out.print(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("------------------------------------ ");
    String original = "Welcome to the word reversing program";
    wordReverse(original);
    System.out.println("Orginal Sentence :::: "+original);
    System.out.println("Reverse Sentence :::: "+wordReverse(original));
}

public static String wordReverse(String original){

    StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer(original);

    Stack<Character> charStack = new Stack<Character>();

    while (string.hasMoreTokens()){

    String temp = string.nextToken();

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i ++){

    charStack.push(temp.charAt(i));
}
    charStack.push(' ');
}

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while(!charStack.empty()){
    result.append(charStack.pop());
}

    return result.toString();   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class reverseStr {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testsa[] = { "", " ", "       ", "a ", " a", " aa bd  cs " };
    for (String tests : testsa) {
        System.out.println(tests + "|" + reverseWords2(tests) + "|");
    }
}

public static String reverseWords2(String s) {
    String[] sa;
    String out = "";
    sa = s.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < sa.length; i++) {
        String word = sa[sa.length - 1 - i];
        // exclude "" in splited array
        if (!word.equals("")) {
            //add space between two words
            out += word + " ";
        }
    }
    //exclude the last space and return when string is void
    int n = out.length();
    if (n > 0) {
        return out.substring(0, out.length() - 1);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

}

This can pass in leetcode

Comment: Can you add more of an explanation to your answer?