# Reversing string stack java

Tags: java

So I'm attempting to create a object that essentially reverses a string someone inputs. I was able to get it to reverse the word order but I need to get it to reverse the words themselves using a stack so this is my code to input the letters into the stack.

```
public class Reverser
{
   private Stack<String> stack;

   public Reverser()
   {
     stack = new Stack<String>();
   }

   public String evaluate(String expr)
   {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(expr);

     char letter;
     String sentence="";
     String rSent="";
     String word="";

     while(in.hasNext())
     {
       sentence = in.next();

       for (int i = 1; i <= sentence.length(); i++)
       {
           while (i <= sentence.length())
           {
             letter = sentence.charAt(i);
             word += letter;
           }
          stack.push(word);        
        }
     }
     while (!stack.isEmpty())
     {
     word = stack.pop();
     rSent += word;
     }
   return rSent;
   }  
}
```

It compiles fine without issue, but when I run my driver

```
 public class StringReversing
  {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
       String sentence, result, again;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      do
      {
         Reverser evaluator = new Reverser();
         System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
         sentence = in.nextLine();

         result = evaluator.evaluate(sentence);
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Your sentence reversed is:");
         System.out.println(result);

         System.out.println("Would you like to reverse another sentence [Y/N]?");
         again = in.nextLine();
         System.out.println();
      }
      while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
   }
}
```

Now I enter a sentence and I get nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I was able to get it to reverse the word order but I need to get it to reverse the words themselves using a stack"? Are you required to use a stack as part of some assignment question? Why not use StringBuilder.reverse?

Comment: Yes it's an assignment that asks me to use a Stack to reverse the letters of the words. Initially I was able to get it to reverse the word order-- Have a nice day. Turned into day.niceaHave

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reversing characters in each word in a sentence - Stack Implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544966/reversing-characters-in-each-word-in-a-sentence-stack-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

You get an endless loop:

```
       for (int i = 1; i <= sentence.length(); i++)
       {
           while (i <= sentence.length())
           {
             letter = sentence.charAt(i);
             word += letter;
           }
          stack.push(word);        
        }
```

The inner `while` loop is an endless loop because i will be ever the same and lower then `sentence.length()`.

And arrays in java are zero based. You `for` loop shoud start at zero.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this already solve your requirement?

```
String input = "I like this CAFEBABE.";
System.out.println("reversed: " + new StringBuilder(input).reverse());
```

Comment: No it asks me to use a Stack to reverse the letters in the words.

Comment: Then you should amend your question a bit to make this requirement clear. With an example for the input and the expeceted output. Maybe with all already given comments you're able to solve your problem. If not. Update your question with your new achievements.